# Solarized dark + Zsh for terminal looks off

Tags: terminal

In some cases, I can't use iTerm2 and have to use the default terminal. The text is extremely hard to read, especially the black text on dark blue background. Is there a reason it's not the same as the iTerm2 Solarized theme? Is there a way to fix this? I imported the theme from the same themes file: http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a *good* way to fix this. As it states in [the documentation](https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070#iterm2)

> iTerm2 has better color fidelity than the built in Terminal, so your
> themes will look better.

That being said, you can edit the color of the prompt via the terminal preferences.

Hope this helps!